# Deleting range of lines from a text file in linux command-line?

Tags: text-editors, text-editing

I have a example.txt file with 280 lines of text. I only want to keep first 80 lines and delete rest lines ?

Comment: Does it has to be using command-line, or is Powershell okay too (assuming we're on windows here, not linux or mac-os?)

Comment: I have Termux in my android phone.

Answer (score 2):

Android phones are off-subject here, but Linux is on-subject.

In Linux, this is very easy using the
[head command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html):

```
head -n 80 input-file > output-file
```

But there exist numerous other methods using other utilities.
If this command doesn't exist in your environment, check if `sed` does exist.